# How can I do an average reverse in c#?

Tags: c#, function, average, inverse

I need to create a function that if i enter a number, return 3 numbers that your averange is the same number that I pass

for example

if i entered the number 3,92 the return value is a list of numbers 3,89 3,57 4,3 (Randomize)

Comment: You question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: makes no sense?

Comment: on `x` input, `return new double[] {x, x, x}`

Comment: Did you try this on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method that will do just that.

```
public double[] AverageReverse(double targetAverage, double range)
{
    var r = new Random(); // TODO: Cache it between calls to avoid "why does ny Random class only produce the same numbers?"
    var n1 = targetAverage - r.NextDouble() * range;
    var n2 = targetAverage + r.NextDouble() * range;
    var n3 = 3 * targetAverage - (n1 + n2);

    return new[] { n1, n2, n3 };
}
```

Example:

```
var ar = AverageReverse(3.92, 0.5);
// returns (example):
//   3,76575929136284 
//   3,98495292557634 
//   4,00928778306082 
// average:
//   3.92
```

The way it works is that by solving the following equation:

```
average = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3
```

for n3 gives:

```
    average             = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3
3 * average             =  n1 + n2 + n3
3 * average - (n1 + n2) =            n3
```

thus:

```
n3 = 3 * average - (n1 + n2)
```